# Avoiding low obstacles with turtlebot 2 and ASUS xtion pro camera

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do autonomous navigation with a turtlebot2 equipped with an ASUS xtion pro but it has a hard time seeing low obstacles.  The camera is mounted at 0.43 meters and it only detects obstacles if they are around the same height.  The robot can't even detect trash cans that are around 0.3 meters high.  The result is that the robot continuously plans paths through these obstacles and ends up getting stuck.

In my costmap_common_params.yaml, I have max_obstacle_height set at 0.6 and min_obstacle_height set at 0.15.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is a view of the camera setup:

[image: turtlebot]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230583/avoiding-low-obstacles-with-turtlebot-2-and-asus-xtion-pro-camera/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-03-31**:
Please add details about your setup, e.g. how do you interface the xtion with the costmap (depthimage_to_laserscan)? And how you mount the xtion.

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-31**:
I'm not sure what you mean by the interface between the xtion and the costmap but I'm using the default settings. I believe I'm using Depthimage_to_laserscan.  I edited my question with a picture of the laser setup.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-04-01**:
Make sure you are really using depthimage to laserscan. Your xtion is mounted very high and the default of the node is use only the middle of the picture, see [1.3 LaserScan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan#LaserScan). Note that the costmap is 2d.

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-04-01**:
I am in fact using depthimage_to_laserscan.  I will consider lowering the camera as well.  Does the costmap always have to be in 2D?  Is this a limitation with the software or with the xtion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just increase the scan_height of depthimage_to_laserscan. The default is 1px in the middle of the picture.
Use rviz to display the /scan topic. Now increase scan_height until you see your trash can or whatever else you want to see in your scan output.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-04-01**:
thanks this worked!